# Automated Machine Learning (autoML) progress comparable with normal machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, automatic-algorithms

autoML is a very convenient model for beginner to explore on Machine Learning and Deep Learning. The process itself rapidly growing and many ML algorithm can be found in autoML, but hardly to be analyses and interpret, the algorithm itself automates the data exploration, feature engineering and assess the best model.

I have build an autoML model that have 9 models that are discriminant analysis, ensemble, kernel classification, k-nearest neighbor, linear classification, naïve bayes, neural network, support vector machine and binary decision tree. autoML choose neural network as the best model. I have fixed and play around on the number of iterations to optimize the learning and I am using bayesian optimizier.

1. I would like to know how and why autoML choose Neural Network as the best model? Is it solely based on accuracy?
2. How does bayesian optimizer influence the number of iterations, I hardly found any reference that relates bayesian optimizer with the iterations.

Comment: This question will be unlikely to attract useful answers because it is so sparse on details. What result do you want to interpret? Are you asking about how a particular tool works? Do you have a specific example that you are trying to understand? Please [edit] to explain what you've done, what you know, and what you'd like to know.

Comment: Thanks for making those edits. I'm afraid the answers these questions are not particularly illuminating. The answer depends on the software (which you haven't named) and should be declared in the documentation. (1) The software could use any criterion of the software author's choosing. Which one is used should be explained in the documentation. (2) The number of BO iterations usually has a default value, listed in the documentation, which can be replaced by a value that the user declares. If the documentation doesn't answer it, you'll have to read the code or contact the author.

Comment: Hi @Sycorax , im using matlab (fitcauto) to build the models. I might need to dig further on the function itself, in the documentation (https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitcauto.html) they just briefly explain how it works and there is no 'why'. Anyway thanks a lot.